# Instruct GNU linker to ignore float abi mismatch?

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, linker-errors

I'm trying to link some object files built with `float-abi=hard`, to some object files built with `float-abi=soft`. The main ABI is `apcs-gnu` which all object files use, and the CPU is an ARM9.

The linker (binutils 2.28) reports a bunch of errors such as :

```
..../arm-eabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file c:/test/old.o
..../arm-eabi/bin/ld: error: c:/test/old.o uses FPA instructions, whereas New does not
..../arm-eabi/bin/ld: c:/test/old.o uses hardware FP, whereas New uses software FP
```

However, neither object uses any floating point at all.  Clearly the linker is detecting the mismatch from the object file metadata, not from any actual function calls.

Is it possible to instruct the linker to ignore this and link anyway?  Because there is no use of floating point, I expect there would not actually be any issues due to the float-ABI mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any pre-existing flags for this.  Instead I edited `binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c` to turn those errors into warnings, and rebuilt.  This appears to have worked, the resulting binaries loaded and ran correctly on my target system.